# NoNodeAvailableException when installing elasticsearch plugin in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm developing a grails web-app (currently on my local machine) that needs to query elasticsearch on a server on my network.

I have taken the following steps:

Added the following line in BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
        ...
        runtime ":elasticsearch:0.0.3.4"
        ...
    }
```

I have also added the following to Config.groovy:

```
elasticSearch {
    client.mode = 'transport'
    client.hosts = [
        [host:'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port:9200]
    ]
    disableAutoIndex = 'true'
}
```

To eliminate firewall issues etc have run the query using curl and it works fine:

```
curl -XGET 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{...}
```

But I am getting the following:

```
|Running Grails application
Error |
2014-10-23 09:17:52,278 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
Message: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
->>  273 | ensureNodesAreAvailable in org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    192 | execute   in     ''
|     81 | execute . in org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClusterAdminClient
|     73 | execute   in     ''
|    118 | health .  in org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClusterAdminClient
|    154 | installMappings in org.grails.plugins.elasticsearch.mapping.SearchableClassMappingConfigurator
|     51 | configureAndInstallMappings in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I've read numerous other answers on here for similar errors but nothing I've tried is working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transport is done on port *9300* (not on the HTTP port *9200*).  Also check this port to be open then.

If it still fails, check also to use the right `cluster.name`.  It is `elasticsearch` by default, so if you have not changed it in your server/cluster, there is no need for it.

Otherwise please add the new insights on your question.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the port to 9300 got rid of the error. I assumed that it would be 9200 as the curl query was. You don't happen to know of any examples or tutorials on doing a search? I have the json and I just want to do the search and use the result but I can't find a simple example anywhere.

Comment: Not directly, as i dont' use the plugin.  but according to http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/searching.html there is `elasticsearchService.search()` which seems to let you do that.  If you have other questions please create new ones, as SO is no forum format.